# Flipping the face normals in threeJS

Tags: three.js, reverse, normals, face

For RingGeometry and PlaneGeometry, I am having trouble with face normals when it comes to printing the stl file I generate from object mesh. I am wondering if there is a way to flip the face normals without changing the orientation of the mesh?

Comment: I think you mean PlaneGeometry?

Comment: @prisoner849 Yes, a typo.

Comment: In stl format, to calculate normals you have to use the right-hand rule for the order of vertices in a triangle. But I think you know about it already. Can you provide more information? For example, what you have in a scene, what you expected to get and what you really get in the exported stl file.